# How to block utorrent by using Squid proxy (fedora 10 or RHEL5)

Tags: proxy, squid

Can Any one suggest me that how to block the utorrent on my Lan (windows XP and Vista clients)  by using Squid proxy (Fedora 10 or RHEL5). I am really got confused while trying to google for this.

Answer (score 5):

Configure your firewall to default deny for all office traffic unless specifically allowed.

Require all Web traffic to route through your proxy.

If your users are unable to access the Internet directly, it will be substantially more difficult for them to use advanced protocols like BitTorrent.

While using SQUID acls will be substantially more limited in scope and be easily circumvented, you could use something like:

```
acl extensiondeny url_regex -i "/etc/squid/extensiondeny"
acl download method GET
http_access deny extensiondeny download
http_access deny extensiondeny
```

Within "/etc/squid/extensiondeny":

```
\.torrent$
```

For more information see:

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/

Comment: Warner, thank you for your fast reply. Is it okay If I block the downloading of *.torrent files ???
If it is then suggest me how do I block the download or opening or *.torrent files ? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I would use squidguard in conjunction with squid to block torrent sites.  This won't prevent other programs from working, though, like limewire, etc.  You would likely need to utilize GPO and/or restrictive rights on the users' machines.

Answer (score 0):

To block Bittorrent connections, either Snort in inline IPS mode or the [Netfilter IPPP2P module](http://www.ipp2p.org/docu_en.html) can be used.